# Agrupar dois arrays de objectos em porwershell

Tags: array, powershell

Olá,

Tenho dois arrays de objectos, tenho que agrupá-los. Isto é, percorrer a lista (array de objetos) dos "car" e quando existe propriedades no array property_list adiciono a esse objecto, que é um array de objectos do tipo property, que está contido num array de propriedades.

Quero que, no fim, tenha o array de objetos "car", com uma propriedade no objeto chamada Properties que contenha um array de properties vinda do array property_list, caso o car não contenha property é inserido um array vazio.

Código:

```
foreach($p in $car_list) {
        $Property =  $property_list.Where({$_.Id -eq $p.Id}) | Select-Object -Property Name,Value
        if(-Not (($null -eq $Property ) -And (@($Property ).Count -eq 0)) ) {
            $p = $p | Add-Member -NotePropertyMembers @{Properties=$Property }
        } else {
            $p = $p | Add-Member -NotePropertyMembers @{Properties=@()}
        }
}
```

O problema é que o código não é eficiente. O array dos car chega aos 200000 posições e em que cada posição é um objecto com várias propridades e o array das propriedades também chega a esses valores. O script demora horas sem fim a executar.

Alguma forma de otimizar este agrupamento de arrays?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talvez o que esteja reduzindo a sua performance eh a seguinte linha:
`$Property =  $property_list.Where({$_.Id -eq $p.Id}) | Select-Object -Property Name,Value`

Faca um experiemento:
Remova essa linha 
do seu loop e de um valor fixo ao seu `$Proprty`. Se a performance melhorar, um jeito que voce pode tentar melhorar o seu codigo eh criar um dicionario onde as chaves sao os `$p.Id` e o valor eh o `$Property`, assim seu acesso ao property sera O(1).

Comment: Sim, foi a solução que acabei por encontrar. Construi um hashmap em que o Id é a key e as propriedades são o value. Melhorou bastante os tempos.